# Can't find List ID for a Saved RSS Entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss, feed, feedjira

I’m building an RSS feed using the Feedjirra gem with the option to save feed entries into a list. When I try to edit the saved entries to add tags, or delete an entry, I get an error that it cannot find the list id even though I am using a list global variable.

I have not nested my saved entries so I may also have a routing error. I also had set up the option to manually enter links into the lists page and put them under a separate controller. I can edit and delete links I've manually entered just fine, but not from the feed.

First of all, the error:

```
Started GET "/entries/9/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-19 20:58:40 -0700
Processing by EntriesController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find List without an ID):
app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:22:in `edit'
```

Here is the feed page where I’m saving the entries:

```
<% @feeds.each do |feed| %>
      <p class="feed_url">
        <%= link_to feed.url, feed %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_feed_path(feed), class: "blue" %> 
        <%= link_to "Delete", feed_path(feed), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this feed url?' }, class: "blue" %>
      </p>

      <div class="entry_wrapper">
        <div class="entry_box">
          <% feed.entries.each do |entry| %>
            <p class="entry_title"><%= sanitize link_to entry.title, entry.url %></p>


            <div class="select_tag">
              <%= form_tag entries_path do %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :url, entry.url %>
                <%= select_tag :list, options_from_collection_for_select(@lists, :id, :name) %>
                <%= submit_tag "Add To List", class: "btn" %>
              <% end %>
            </div>

              <p class="entry_info">
                <%= sanitize get_info(entry), length: 30 %>
              </p>


      <% end %>
```

Here is the controller for the saved entries from the feed:

```
def index
 if params[:tag]
  @saved_entries = SavedEntry.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  @tag = params[:tag].capitalize
else
  @saved_entries = SavedEntry.all
end
  authorize @items
end

def create
  @list = List.find(params[:list])
  @saved_entry = SavedEntry.new_with_preview(url: params[:url])
  @saved_entry.list = @list
  @saved_entry.save
  redirect_to request.referer
end

def edit
  @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  @saved_entry = SavedEntry.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @saved_entry = SavedEntry.find(params[:id])

  if @saved_entry.update_attributes(url: params[:url])
    flash[:notice] = "You have updated the entry."
    redirect_to @list
  else
    flash[:notice] = "There was an error. Please try again."
    render :edit
  end
end

 def destroy
  @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  @saved_entry = SavedEntry.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is the list show page:

```
<% @saved_entries.each do |entry| %>
<div class="list_box">
  <div class="list_image"><%= image_tag(entry.image_url) %></div>
  <p>
    <%= link_to entry.url, entry.url, target: "_blank" %><br />
    <br />
    <p>
        Tags: <%= raw entry.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
    </p>
    <% if current_user %>
      <div class="list_edit_delete">
        <small><%= link_to "Edit", edit_entry_path(entry) %></small>
        <small><%= link_to "Delete", entry_path(entry), method: :delete %></small>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

And saved_entries edit.html.erb

```
<div class="lists">

  <%= form_for [@list, @saved_entry] do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :url, "URL", class: "" %>
   <%= f.text_field :url, class: "" %><br />

    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "d_button" %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

If anyone can make senses of this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@list = List.find(params[:list_id])
```

`params[:list_id]` must be undefined, i.e. `nil`, which raises this error. I don't see you passing it in

```
<small><%= link_to "Edit", edit_entry_path(entry) %></small>
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. However, I added @list to my links and it is still unable to find the id. I did it as follows:     
    <small><%= link_to "Edit", edit_entry_path(@list, entry) %></small>

Comment: And are you sure that the list is defined? Maybe try `edit_entry_path(entry, list_id: @list.id)`.

Comment: Alright, you got me super freakin' far. Thank you. So calling it the way you suggested actually led me to another error. My feed edit page had a routing error. Turns out that I had routes for the manually entered links but not for the links saved from the news feed. Huge help. Thank you.